# Trying to write a function that takes a cardinal direction and coords, returns new coordinates

Tags: python

I'm currently trying to write a function that takes a str of north, east, south, and/or west and then a starting location for both an x and y coordinate on a grid.
I'm currently trying to figure out how I could take a string that, for example, reads "EWNeWn" and can separate it so a program can interpret it to follow directions.

If the direction is "N", the y-coord increases by 1. "E" increases the x-coord by 1. "S" decreases the y-coord by 1. and W decreases the x-coord by 1.
It's supposed to be returned as a tuple.

I thought I was on the right track at first but I'm not really sure anymore, I'm quite new to this.
Any help??
Here's my code:

```
def movement(string, x, y):
if (string == 'N', 'n'):
    y += 1
    return (x, y)
elif (string == 'E', 'e'):
    x += 1
    return (x, y)
elif (string == 'S', 's'):
    y -= 1
    return (x, y)
elif (string == 'W', 'w'):
    x -= 1
    return (x, y)
```

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
Your posted code has syntax errors, and you never call your function.  If you don't know whether or not the function works so far, you need to test it; this is not yet a Stack Overflow question.

Comment: What do you think `if (string == 'N', 'n')` evaluates to?

Comment: @user202729 hover over the link, and that expansion appears quite readily.

Answer (score 0):

Something like `(string == 'N', 'n')` wouldn't work. That would make a tuple of the first element being `True` or `False` (the condition is `string == 'N'`), and the second element would be simply `'n'`.

As OP mentioned in the comments, try this:

```
def movement(string, x, y):
    for char in string:
        if char.lower() == 'n':
            y += 1
        elif char.lower() == 'e':
            x += 1
        elif char.lower() == 's':
            y -= 1
        elif char.lower() == 'w':
            x -= 1
    return (x, y)
print(movement('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 0, 0))
```

Comment: Ahhh I see. Do you know how I would be able to change this function so I can pass multiple letters through the string at once??

Comment: @heth1234 Done. In my **Edited:** part. Remember to upvote and accept if it's useful :)

Comment: Hmm it's still not working. Just returning as "None" but thanks anyway

Comment: Do you know how I can reassign the x and y variables for after they have been changed?

Comment: @heth1234 Edited my answer, check it out

Comment: Wait, what did you change asides from the print statement?

Comment: @heth1234 I only do `return (x, y)` at the end. Remember to upvote and accept if it helps.